# npm ERR! It downloads really slow and after sometime the npm just errors and stops altogether

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the `npx create-react-app my-app` and after I enter it, it just becomes blank for a good minute and then starts downloading, but the download bar won't move but the text changes every 15 seconds. I've installed node.js but I'm not sure if I changed anything from it.

Are there any other ways I can use ReactJS?

I've tried more than once and it's just saying the same error, how do I fix this?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiIHt.png)

Please bare with me it's my first time trying to use it.

Comment: Try clearing cache and logs. Command `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: This error usually indicates that your internet connection is slow and/or flaky. Is it stable for other use-cases? Npm doesn't report any recent issues on their [status page](https://status.npmjs.org/). If it continues to not work and your internet is fine, you could use something like Codesandbox, Stackblitz, or JSFiddle.

Comment: If you're using vpn, private dns or proxy server, then try to turn them off. And if these are not the cases then try a better network connection.

Comment: I tried using this command but it said: npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.